# Chnage color of SVG as it passes through a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, svg

I am trying to find a way where i can take an SVG that is the logo of my site. It is sticky and as you scroll down the site the background changes from dark gray to white and i want to change the SVG logo from white to orange as it passes over the div. Whats the best way to achieve this? Similar to what is on this site with the ball on the right. It changes colors as the background changes --> https://daly.nyc/

Comment: Why not use the method that site does? Use fixed co-positioned logos with a relatively positioned clip rectangle.

Comment: For anyone trying to do this I found a solution here => https://codepen.io/mikeK/pen/VGPdyJ